# Not adding JARs to staging folder on Google Cloud when using Maven

Tags: java, maven, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

I'm running integration tests on the cloud for the Google Cloud Dataflows that I have written; checking that they read from Pub/Sub and write to BigQuery correctly, but when using Maven (mvn clean install), the staging folder is not populated with the required JARs. The only JAR that appears is a surefirebooter.jar. As a result, I get a NoClassDefFoundError for PipelineOptions (most likely because it is the first class from a dependency that's trying to be referenced) in the Stackdriver logs, and consequently the tests fail. Since they're running on the cloud I am indeed using a DataflowRunner as opposed to a DirectRunner.

When I run the integration tests from my IDE they work fine; the staging folder is populated with all the JARs and all is well. Also, when I run the tests using Maven but with a DirectRunner the tests run successfully, thus my problem only occurs when using Maven and a DataflowRunner. I assume that problem therefore lies with the pom.xml file, which I have given below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>group</groupId>
    <artifactId>artifact</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>


            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud.dataflow</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-cloud-dataflow-java-sdk-all</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0-beta3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.25</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.25</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0-M3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2-beta</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Anyone know why this is happening and how I may resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

When staging files, the Dataflow runner will automatically stage the the classes available to the current class loader. I believe that surefire plays some tricks with the classloader to make the tests easier to run.

One option would be to specify filesToStage on the pipeline options, which will override the normal "detect JARs to stage from the class loader". Alternatively, look at how surefire is managing the classpath, and make sure the SDK JARs are available in the classloader the test is running in.

Comment: Seems like adding:
`<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.20</version>
                <configuration>
                    <useSystemClassLoader>false</useSystemClassLoader>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>`
Fixed the problem but I'm not sure if this will introduce more problems later on.